# What is the source of initial transactions of bitcoin?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, development, coinbase-transaction, genesis-block

Sorry, if I am wrong or silly!

It is understood that:

a) Satoshi Nakamoto sent the first transaction to developer Hal Finney on January 12, 2009, the genesis block contains 1,073 transactions and he got 50BTC as block reward, which is non spendable by design.

b) Coins are mined during block publishing.

c) A coinbase transaction must be 100 blocks deep before you can spend its outputs

d) Coins don't merge

e) For each transaction, sender should have group of input coins, whose sum should be greater than equal to sum of transaction amount and transaction fee.

What is the total amount of all those transactions and how they got BTCs for the initial transactions?

Comment: New Bitcoin are only created when a new block is mined. The new coins are collected as "subsidy" reward from the successful miner. The miner reward can be found in the coinbase transaction, which is always the first transaction in a block. The coinbase is constructed similarly to other transactions, but doesn't reference any previous output. But since its outputs have non-zero amounts, coins are created with the coinbase. Search for other coinbase-related questions, there are several related ones.

Comment: Re: *”the genesis block contain 1,073 transactions”*, this is false. The genesis block only includes an (unspendable) coinbase transaction. The payout address for that coinbase transaction has been sent many transactions since then, but they would have been included in subsequent blocks.

Comment: Statement :  "The genesis block has received 1,073 transactions..." Reference: https://news.bitcoin.com/bitcoins-quirky-genesis-block-turns-eight-years-old-today/

Comment: @AVA that statement is technically incorrect; it should read *"the bitcoin address from the genesis block coinbase transaction has been the recipient of 1,073 transactions to date.."*. Saying *"a block received a transaction"* makes no sense. A block *contains* transactions, it does not receive them. The genesis block had just one single transaction in it. See: https://blockstream.info/block/000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f

Answer (score 1):

> **What is the total amount of all those transactions**

You can see Bitcoin's genesis block here:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Genesis_block

You can easily examine early blocks by using the block height in any [blockchain explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer). For example [here](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block-height/1)

> **how they got BTCs for the initial transactions?**

Mined blocks can be [empty](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/61919/13866) (contain no transactions other than the "coinbase" mining reward). I guess this can be the case when the mempool is empty or when all the pending transactions therein have unattractive fees.

Answer (score 1):

**The genesis block is block 0:**
[block 0](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f)

-the reward went to the address 1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa.

**The first regular *transaction*** (from Nakamoto to Finney) is in [block #170](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block-index/15019)

[txhash=f4184fc596403b9d638783cf57adfe4c75c605f6356fbc91338530e9831e9e16](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/f4184fc596403b9d638783cf57adfe4c75c605f6356fbc91338530e9831e9e16)

-sent from 
12cbQLTFMXRnSzktFkuoG3eHoMeFtpTu3S to 1Q2TWHE3GMdB6BZKafqwxXtWAWgFt5Jvm3 with the change being deposited back to the sending address. These coins were over 100 confirms.

**The 1073 transactions you are talking** about was probably correct at the time of writing, but they are talking about the number of transactions sending coins to the address in the genesis block over the life of bitcoin.

-There have been 1,508 transactions (as of right now) which sent coins to the address in the genesis block, so now that address holds 66.91839465 BTC, 50 of which were from the genesis transaction. That means there have been 16.91839465 BTC sent to it. ([1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa))

Comment: Small correction: the block reward of the Genesis block was sent to a pay-to-pubkey output which doesn't have an address format and is misleadingly represented on some block explorers by the p2pkh address that could be derived from that pubkey. This p2pkh address is what got paid by the transactions you mention. The output of the Genesis block is unspendable as it did not get added to the UTXO set of the original client and the Genesis block is hard coded as the start of the blockchain and therefore does not get evaluated like other blocks by full nodes